# Convert a column with both MM-DD-YYYY & DD-MM-YYYY dates to just MM-DD-YYYY?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-cleaning

I am having trouble finding a solution to getting the date column on my table to properly convert/change from a mix of *mm-dd-yyyy* and *dd-mm-yyyy* to just *mm-dd-yyyy*.

The proper dates in the column with the *mm-dd-yyyy* format are separated by "/" and the rest with the dd-mm-yyyy format are separated with "-". The data I am using comes from the [Kaggle Walmart Dataset.](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mikhail1681/walmart-sales/data)

| Date |
| --- |
| 5/2/2010 |
| 12/2/2010 |
| 19-02-2010 |
| 26-02-2010 |
| 5/3/2010 |
| 12/3/2010 |
| 19-03-2010 |
| 26-03-2010 |

I imported the dataset into SQL Server as a flat file CSV which imported the data as varchar(50) and I could manipulate the other columns easily to other data types (DECIMAL and INT) but the [Date] column has been giving me trouble and I receive this message after trying to CAST the data to 'Date' data type:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My logic is telling me to separate the column into three columns using "/" and "-" as delimiters but it would still leave me with the issue of the *mm-dd* and *dd-mm* mix up.

I have two main questions from this.

1. Is the message I am receiving due to the dates being mixed so SQL is considering the column as a character string?
2. Is there an optimal way to get all of the dates into a *mm-dd-yyyy* format?

Any assistance for solving is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The data *IS* a string, so yes of course its considering it as a string. Your goal shouldn't be to get the date in any specific format, it should be to get the dates stored as a proper date datatype... from there you can display them however you like.

Comment: Given the dates are in multiple formats, you might need to try 2 conversions using `try_convert` with different format parameters.

Comment: There is no reliable way as of course a string representing a date, where the string is `01/02/2012` might be either the 1st February or 2nd January. ... If you have a "preferred" format and you are willing to accept some errors you could implement a function which tried different formats one by one using `try_convert` and let the first matching format win?

Comment: Alternatively, if you want ambiguous formats to become NULL then you can implement a function which tries different formats, and returns a value only if there is exactly one matching format.

Comment: Unfortunately when it comes to "cleaning data" the rules are not scientific facts, the come from the business - "Supposing we get a date such as ... what should we do? Discard it?"

Comment: Important learning as a newbie, don't ever store dates as strings

Comment: `Is there an optimal way to get all of the dates into a mm-dd-yyyy format` **no** because this is not an optimal format. Instead get all dates into `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: From the examples given all the cases could match DD/MM/YYYY,with only the separator changing. However this is just a guess given the limited data. I would outright reject the data import for being improperly formated and request that the data provider gives a consistent format.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! WIll try these methods and respond with what works for my case. I was taking the bad and improperly stored data as is when I imported from the CSV to SQL with the intention of cleaning it up there.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @DaleK I see the option on the answers. For the original question, Charlieface's answer is the most correct. Thank you for the assistance! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming you are correct** in your assumption:

> The proper dates in the column with the mm-dd-yyyy format are separated by "/" and the rest with the dd-mm-yyyy format are separated with "-".

Then you can do

```sql
ISNULL(
  TRY_CONVERT(date, YourValue, 105),
  TRY_CONVERT(date, YourValue, 101)
)
```

See the list of data and time styles [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles).

Answer (score 3):

If you genuinely have dates in both formats, with nothing else to indicate how to handle them, it will be **impossible** to accurately determine the correct format for every date.

The reason is the stored values are ambiguous. For example, given a value like `01-02-2024`, the correct interpretation could be **either** `January 2nd` or `February 1st`. Given enough rows, you're certain to have cases where both are correct.

Other systems handle this kind of thing by parsing the dates on the front end, using the cultural settings from the original user's system or browser, and then **storing as binary date values instead of strings in the first place.** Once we load them into the database as strings, it's **too late** to fix the issue.

---

> My logic is telling me to separate the column into three columns using "/" and "-" as delimiters but it would still leave me with the issue of the mm-dd and dd-mm mix up.

No. Most databases have a dedicated `date` or `datetime` type for this. **Use that.** Many even have newer types that do better for timezones or offsets... because it turns out this stuff is *surprisingly hard*, and the point is to lean on that tooling and take advantage of the lessons the database provider had to learn the hard way.

For databases that don't have such a type, still use one column, but always store the values using the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) "yyyy-MM-dd" format. This not only removes confusion ([all common cultural formats that put the year first also put month before day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_date_formats_by_country)), but keeps the components in order of time significance from largest (year) to smallest (day), and with appropriate 0-padding, so natural sorting and indexing will be correct.

Comment: But even though it's ISO and nobody on earth would do this, SQL Server can still mess up a string in the form `yyyy-MM-dd` and [assume it is `yyyy-dd-MM`](https://dbfiddle.uk/0dTaoEHE). The only truly safe date-only string format in SQL Server is `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Correct. And I've used your posts on this matter as a reference when talking about SQL Server :) The ISO format is only for databases that do not have native date/datetime support.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to make it a little clearer for anyone who skipped the first part of that sentence (like I did on first read). :-)

Comment: I bolded some of the text, and split it out to a new paragraph, to make skipping past that part less likely. Not that this post is likely to end up getting more views now (the time/view decay law and all that), but you never know what will get picked up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, the only way you can know for sure what the ambiguous dates are, is if you know what format they were entered in.

However taking a guess that its `dd-mm-yyyy`, because `26-03-2010` has to be that format, then `try_convert(date, [Date], 103)` using format `103` works. c.f. [convert format reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
select DateString
  , try_convert(date, DateString, 103) [Date]
from (
  values
  ('5/2/2010'),
  ('12/2/2010'),
  ('19-02-2010'),
  ('26-02-2010'),
  ('5/3/2010'),
  ('12/3/2010'),
  ('19-03-2010'),
  ('26-03-2010')
) x (DateString);
```

Returns:

| DateString | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 5/2/2010 | 2010-02-05 |
| 12/2/2010 | 2010-02-12 |
| 19-02-2010 | 2010-02-19 |
| 26-02-2010 | 2010-02-26 |
| 5/3/2010 | 2010-03-05 |
| 12/3/2010 | 2010-03-12 |
| 19-03-2010 | 2010-03-19 |
| 26-03-2010 | 2010-03-26 |

Comment: This snippet solved my issue when I applied its structure to my code

```
SELECT Walmart_sales1.date,
  TRY_CONVERT(date, Walmart_sales1.Date, 103) [Date_n]
FROM Walmart_sales1
```

It gave me a similar output which provided dates in line with what I needed.

Thank you!

Comment: @justcallmegabe it might work, but it doesn't do what you ask for in the question, where you say some dates are UK format and some are US. Charlieface's does that

Comment: I was able to get successful runs from both yours and Charlieface's answers. For my question on the original post, Charlieface's is the best way to get the dates reorganized in the way that I needed. I made a rookie mistake and did not take the whole dataset into account to correlate the temperature column with the dates. Your solution makes more sense as the temperatures logged for a single store are consistent with the the dates moving into the warmer months of the year.

Answer (score 0):

`MM-dd-yyyy` are already in datetype format ,you only need to cast them into `date` or `datatime` datatype

Try this,

```
declare @t table(col varchar(50))
insert into @t values('12-24-2023'),('24-12-2023')

select cast(col as datetime) from @t where isdate(col)=1
union all
select try_convert(datetime,col,105) from @t where isdate(col)=0
```